# How can i capture storport health log using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, event-viewer

i'm new to ps scripting , i want to capture event logs of Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health using powershell
[all this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohtpS.png)

i have tried these commands but getting error
Get-EventLog -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health -InstanceId 511

Get-EventLog -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health
also tried Get-WinEvent

Any help will be thankfull

Answer (score 2):

Try the below to get the object `[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord]`. You can replace the search filters for what you are looking out for:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health' | Where-Object {
    $_.Id -eq 512
}
```

You can then inspect the object by piping `Get-Member`.

As [Thor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331399/thor) has suggested, you can run the `ToXml()` on the object to get all the information you are looking for.

For example:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health' | 
select -f 1                                                       | 
% { $_.toxml() }
```

Gives:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-StorPort" Guid="{c4636a1e-7986-4646-bf10-7bc3b4a76e8e}"/>
    <EventID>512</EventID>
    <Version>5</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>201</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x200000000000040</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-08-17T08:49:25.4504819Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>318</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation/>
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="2852"/>
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health</Channel>
    <Computer>HF-NB-26.landsnet.far.local</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="PortNumber">0</Data>
    <Data Name="PathID">0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetID">0</Data>
    <Data Name="LUN">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ClassDeviceGuid">{6582d3ef-ac27-f50c-c6a3-c718a5ed6004}</Data>
    <Data Name="AdapterGuid">{027f5e62-3c52-11ea-ab68-806e6f6e6963}</Data>
    <Data Name="MiniportName">stornvme</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorId">NVMe    </Data>
    <Data Name="ProductId">WDC PC SN730 SDB</Data>
    <Data Name="SerialNumber">19348C800681        _2017</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDevice">true</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemUptime_s">1295298</Data>
    <Data Name="CriticalWarning">0</Data>
    <Data Name="NvmeHealthLogLength">216</Data>
    <Data Name="NvmeHealthLog">004201640A0200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005F0662020000000000000000000000009ABCD101000000000000000000000000E8BD62310000000000000000000000007604842B000000000000000000000000EE050000000000000000000000000000330A000000000000000000000000000030060000000000000000000000000000490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorSpecificLogPageCode">0</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorSpecificLogPageVersion">0</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorSpecificLogLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorSpecificLog"/>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Or to only extract `Event.EventData.Data`:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health' |
select -f 1                                                       |
% { ([xml]$_.toxml()).event.eventdata.data }
```

Output:

```
Name                         #text
----                         -----
PortNumber                   0
PathID                       0
TargetID                     0
LUN                          0
ClassDeviceGuid              {6582d3ef-ac27-f50c-c6a3-c718a5ed6004}
AdapterGuid                  {027f5e62-3c52-11ea-ab68-806e6f6e6963}
MiniportName                 stornvme
VendorId                     NVMe
ProductId                    WDC PC SN730 SDB
SerialNumber                 19348C800681        _2017
BootDevice                   true
SystemUptime_s               1295298
CriticalWarning              0
NvmeHealthLogLength          216
NvmeHealthLog                004201640A020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
VendorSpecificLogPageCode    0
VendorSpecificLogPageVersion 0
VendorSpecificLogLength      0
VendorSpecificLog
```

Comment: Thanks for response, the command which you shared is giving general tab data , i want event data from details tab

Comment: @shubhamkumar: Most, if not all, of that data is available if you run `ToXML()` on the object

Comment: @Thor I did not actually know that! I will add it in as an edit, soon. Thank you.

Comment: @shubhamkumar: see update for an example